# sqlquery not working giving error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I to write a query for the book database.  The question is to List each author's total earnings in 1995-2000 in descending order.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.author,b.earnings as TOTAL_EARNING
FROM BookAuthor as b lEFT JOIN
     BookPublish
     on b.book=BookPublish.book
WHERE (b.earnings=COUNT(b.earnings)) AND (year BETWEEN 1995 AND 2000)
ORDER BY b.earnings desc ;
```

ERor: Invalid use of group function.

```
create table BookPublish( 
      book varchar(255) ,
      year int,
      publisher varchar(255),
      price int,
      num int,
      PRIMARY KEY (book)
    );

    //INSERT INTO BookPublish VALUES('Math-1',1999,'Mcgraw',120,5000);
    //INSERT INTO BookPublish VALUES('Physics',2001,'Matt Woods',85,2500);
    //INSERT INTO BookPublish VALUES('Chemistry',1996,'McGraw',99,2300);
    //INSERT INTO BookPublish VALUES('Biology',1999,'Krishna',75,2000);
    //INSERT INTO BookPublish VALUES('Economics',2000,'Maze',125,3000);
    //INSERT INTO BookPublish VALUES('Engineering',1994,'ABC',180,8000);
    //INSERT INTO BookPublish VALUES('Medicine',1997,'ABC',180,9000);


    create table BookAuthor( 
      book varchar(255) ,
      author varchar(255) ,
      earnings int,
      PRIMARY KEY (book,author)
    );


    //INSERT INTO BookAuthor VALUES('Math-1','Chris,Norman',12000);
    //INSERT INTO BookAuthor VALUES('Physics','Matt Woods',4000);
    //INSERT INTO BookAuthor VALUES('Chemistry','John Bayer',8200);
    //INSERT INTO BookAuthor VALUES('Biology','Craig S',3000);
    //INSERT INTO BookAuthor VALUES('Economics','Manohar',17000);
    //INSERT INTO BookAuthor VALUES('Engineering','Sterling',13050);
    //INSERT INTO BookAuthor VALUES('Medicine','Craig S',10000);

    create table BookReview( 
      book varchar(255) ,
      reviewer varchar(255) ,
      score int,
      PRIMARY KEY (book,reviewer)  ,
      FOREIGN KEY (book) REFERENCES BookPublish(book)
    );


    //INSERT INTO BookReview VALUES('Math-1','Paul Gray',7);
    //INSERT INTO BookReview VALUES('Math-1','Daphne Merkin',8);
    //INSERT INTO BookReview VALUES('Physics','Daphne Merkin',6);
    //INSERT INTO BookReview VALUES('Chemistry','John',9);
    //INSERT INTO BookReview VALUES('Biology','Jack',10);
    //INSERT INTO BookReview VALUES('Economics','Paul Gray',7.5);
    //INSERT INTO BookReview VALUES('Engineering','Paul Gray',8);
    //INSERT INTO BookReview VALUES('Engineering','Daphne Merkin',7);


    create table BookReference( 
      book varchar(255) ,
      bookreferenced varchar(255) ,
      PRIMARY KEY (book, bookreferenced)  ,
      FOREIGN KEY (book) REFERENCES BookPublish(book)
    );

    //INSERT INTO BookReference VALUES('Math-1','Introduction to Math');
    //INSERT INTO BookReference VALUES('Physics','Foundation of Physics');
    //INSERT INTO BookReference VALUES('Chemistry','Introduction to Chemistry');
    //INSERT INTO BookReference VALUES('Biology','Molecular Biology');
    //INSERT INTO BookReference VALUES('Economics','Micro-Economics');
    //INSERT INTO BookReference VALUES('Engineering','Engineering-1');
```

Comment: I feel you should remove `(b.earnings = COUNT(b.earnings))` by which you won't get proper results as this condition can never become true

Comment: If I remove that then the author Craig is displayed twice.. instead of once with earning of 13000

Comment: I got it, referencing of table is considered a bit wrongly. Earnings would be books sold * price of book. AUTHOR table should only display Author names. There should be a BOOK table that contains the book details only and links author to the AUTHOR table. Later these books publish details can be captured in BOOKPUBLISH table.

Answer (score 3):

You have this in the `where` clause:

```
 b.earnings = COUNT(b.earnings)
```

You cannot mix aggregation and non-aggregation values.

What you want is a `group by`:

```
SELECT ba.author, sum(ba.earnings) as TOTAL_EARNING
FROM BookAuthor as ba lEFT JOIN
     BookPublish bp
     on ba.book = bp.book
WHERE year BETWEEN 1995 AND 2000
GROUP BY ba.author
ORDER BY sum(ba.earnings) desc ;
```

Comment: Can you explain me why I cant add aggregation and non aggregation value ? thanksalot

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9755d/1 @GordonLinoff i have added sql fiddle based on you answer

Comment: @user3342812 . . . Your question doesn't make sense.  The query was *comparing* an aggregation value and non-aggregation.  The easiest way to think about that is that the `where` is conceptually evaluated before the `group by`, so the aggregation function is not yet defined in the `where`.

Comment: AUTHOR             TOTAL_EARNING
Manohar             17000
Chris,Norman     12000
John Bayer     8200
Craig S             13000


This is the output. Craig shouldbe abve John? Its not in dec order for some  reason

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the earnings, ba.earnings will remain same for every column multiplied by BookPublish column hence the total will become wrong. Hence it should remain just ba.earnings without any method. If you want to calculate the earnings based on BookPublish something below should work

```
SELECT b.author, b.book AS book, b.earnings AS TOTAL_EARNING, sum(bp.num) * bp.price AS EARNING
FROM BookAuthor b
LEFT JOIN BookPublish bp ON b.book=bp.book
WHERE year BETWEEN 1995 AND 2000
GROUP BY b.author, b.book
ORDER BY b.earnings desc ;
```

Here I tried to SUM the number of books sold & multiplied with the price, the GROUP BY remains for author and book as every book sold will have different price.
By this you will get multiple author rows which can later be control in your code using for loop over the resultant object

Added on SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9755d/6

Edit - Table structure you can consider improving

```
CREATE TABLE `AUTHORS`(
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fname` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `lname` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `PUBLISHERS` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `phone_no` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `address` TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE `BOOKS` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `publish_year` INT NOT NULL,
    `author_id` INT NOT NULL,
    KEY `author_id` (`author_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `books_author_fk1` FOREIGN KEY `author_id` REFERENCES AUTHORS (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `BOOKPUBLISH` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `book_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `publisher_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `publish_year` INT NOT NULL,
    `price` INT NOT NULL,
    KEY `book_id` (`book_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `bookpublish_book_fk1` FOREIGN KEY `book_id` REFERENCES BOOKS (`id`),
    KEY `publisher_id` (`publisher_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `bookpublish_publisher_fk1` FOREIGN KEY `publisher_id` REFERENCES PUBLISHER (`id`)
);
```

This way you can define your other tables took, BOOKREVIEW & BOOKREFERENCE